# Order by not working for child objects in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-order-by

I want to retrieve child objects sorted on some particular column.
I have parent class Student

```
public class Student {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="STUDENT_ID")
    private long studentId; 

    @Column(name="STUDENT_NAME")
    private String studentName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="student")
    private List<Phone> studentPhoneNumbers ; 
}
```

and child class Phone

```
public class Phone {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="PHONE_ID")
    private long phoneId; 

    @Column(name="PHONE_NO")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name ="UPDATE_TMSTP")
    private Date updateTmstp;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private Student student;
}
```

I am fetching Student object which in turns gives me the list of phone nos. and I want those phone nos to be sorted based on column `updateTmstp` for this I wrote this

```
Student stu = (Student)session.createCriteria(Student.class)
                .createAlias("studentPhoneNumbers", "st").addOrder(Order.desc("st.updateTmstp")).uniqueResult();
```

But it is not working. can someone help me. Did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Under `studentPhoneNumbers` place `orderBy` annotation and on query use Join Fetch to bring all phones eagerly.

Be aware that this means all fecth on `studentPhoneNumbers` will allways generate an `SELECT ... ORDER BY`. If that's not what you want I would suggest sort the collection in code after get the results.